# How can I write this SQL better?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the tables Patient, Service, PatientStatus, Status - a Patient can have multiple statuses discriminated by a Service.

I want to build a view that shows for each service and each patient what their current status is, even if they don't have a status for that service.

I've got some SQL that does this, but can I write it better? (I'm mainly concerned about the inner join on Patient with the 1 = 1)

Here's the SQL:

```
select
    p.Code,
    s.pkServiceId, 
    ps.fkPatientId, 
    ps.fkStatusId, 
    s.Code AS ServiceCode, 
    s.Description AS ServiceDescription, 
    st.Code AS StatusCode, 
    st.Description as StatusDescription, 
    ps.TsStart
from 
    Service s
inner join
    Patient p on 1 = 1
left outer join
      (select
            max(TsStart) AS TsStart, 
            fkPatientId, 
            fkServiceId
        from
            PatientStatus AS ps
        group by
            fkServiceId, fkPatientId
     ) AS psLast on 
        psLast.fkServiceId = s.pkServiceId and 
        psLast.fkPatientId = p.pkPatientId
left outer join
    PatientStatus AS ps ON 
        psLast.TsStart = ps.TsStart and 
        psLast.fkPatientId = ps.fkPatientId and 
        psLast.fkServiceId = ps.fkServiceId 
left outer join
    Status st on
        st.pkStatusId = ps.fkStatusId
```

Comment: You may get a bit more help if you provide a sample dataset and then an example of what you want your data to look like. I have found that is very effective at getting some of our SQL gurus here to bang out a solution quickly.

Comment: Thanks - I'll keep that in mind for the future, though I'm fairly happy that I've solved this myself. I'm primarily a developer but have enough SQL skills to bang out reasonable stuff most of the time :)

Answer (score 4):

Duh... my 1 = 1 is the same as rewriting it as a CROSS JOIN:

from 
    Service s
cross join 
    Patient p

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason that you need the rows to show up for Patient/Services if they don't have a status for that service? It seems like this should be something handled on the front-end to me.

That said, to get what you're looking for I'd probably use the following:

```
SELECT
    P.Code,
    S.pkServiceID,  --Ugh, I hate that naming convention
    PS.fkPatientID,
    PS.fkStatusID,
    S.Code AS ServiceCode,
    S.Description AS ServiceDescription,
    ST.Code AS StatusCode,
    ST.Description AS StatusDescription
    PS.TsStart
FROM
    Patient P
CROSS JOIN Service S
LEFT OUTER JOIN PatientStatus PS ON
    PS.fkPatientID = P.pkPatientID AND
    PS.fkServiceID = S.pkServiceID
LEFT OUTER JOIN PatientStatusPS2 ON
    PS2.fkPatientID = P.pkPatientID AND
    PS2.fkServiceID = S.pkServiceID AND
    PS2.TsStart > PS.TsStart
LEFT OUTER JOIN Status ST ON
    ST.pkStatusID = PS.fkStatusID
WHERE
    PS2.fkPatientID IS NULL
```

Just a quick note... if you have two statuses with the exact same TsStart for the same patient and service then you will get duplicates here. You would get those from your original query as well though. You can code for that if needed. Just change the last line in the join on PS2 to:

```
(PS2.TsStart > PS.TsStart OR (PS2.TsStart = PS.TsStart AND PS2.pkID > PS.pkID))
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip but the front-end prevents the duplicates, though I should probably have a unique constraint in the database as well. And yes, the requirement is to show all services, even those that the patient has never had a status with.

Comment: I understand the requirement, I just think that the front-end should be able to build any "blank" entries without them explicitly being sent back from the database. I know that with most out of the box controls it's easier to just bind to a resultset and be done though.

Answer (score 0):

I've wondered why there is no relationship between Patient and Service table? Why should use " 1 = 1 "?

Assuming that Patient-Service is many to many relationship
...
    Service s
inner join 
     (PatientService ps  inner join Patient p on ps.PCode = p.Code) 
        on s.Code = ps.SCode
...